# Python find words has specific suffixs

Tags: python, string, words, suffix

I am dealing with Chinese NLP Problem.
I find to find word has specific suffixs.
 For example, I have two list!

`suffixs = ['aaa','bbb','cc'.....]`

`words_list = ['oneaaa','twobbb','three','four']`

```
for w in words_list:
    if w has suffix in suffixs:
          func(s,w)
```

I know I can use re package, but re just can deal with less than 100 suffixs,but I have 1000+ suffixs.
I try to use

```
for w in words_list:
    for s in suffixs:
         #suffixs sorted by lenth
         if s is_suffix_of(w):
               func(s,w)
               break
```

But it is too slow.
The func(s,w) could split the word *w* to no_suffix word and suffix.
For example 'oneaaa' to ['one','aaa']，but the func bases on some condition and more complex.So *any* doesn't work here.
So I want to know whether a better way to deal with it.

Comment: What's your `func`, Why you call it with different params?

Comment: it's worth to elaborate whether `func(b,w)` should be called if ANY of "back_fixes" was found in the word OR it should be called for all potential matches

Comment: @FrankAK thank for your attention,I edit my question.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest when the b is the back_fixs of w , trigger the func, and the match rule is heuristic, when the longer back_fix in w, break the infer loop.

Comment: If you say "back-fix", do you mean "suffix"?

Comment: Are you asking how you can test whether a word has a given suffix? That could be done using the `endswith` string method.

Comment: Maybe you should learn about [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yesss! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just wan to see which words have "back-fixes" (the correct term is suffix, BTW), you can just use [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) in combination with `any`

```
for w in words_list:
    if any(w.endswith(b) for b in back_fixs):
          print(w)
```

Or pass all the suffixes to `endswith`, but for that they have to be in a `tuple`, not `list`:

```
back_fixs = tuple(back_fixs)
for w in words_list:
    if w.endswith(back_fixs):
          print(w)
```

If you also need to know *which* suffix matches, you can get the `next`, or `None` if non match:

```
for w in words_list:
    b = next((b for b in back_fixs if w.endswith(b)), None)
    if b:
          print(w, b)
```

Or shorter using `filter`: `b = next(filter(w.endswith, back_fixs), None)`

Or without default, using `try/except`:

```
for w in words_list:
    try:
        print(w, next(filter(w.endswith, back_fixs)))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: +1 for the `endswith(<tuple>)` syntax, I had no idea! I wonder if the performance is acceptable with a thousand suffixes, but only the OP can say.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use **next**  and **endswith** but it was also slow .I deal with news with about thousands words .One article cost 7 seconds.

Comment: @Cauchyzhou If the suffixes has a certain maximum length, say 3 characters, it might be faster to put all the suffixes into a `set` and then test for the last 1, 2, or 3 characters of each word whether those are in the set.

Comment: I am sorry, I find the reason why is slow. The func's condition judgement is slow.Anyhow, thank you. **endswit**h is a better solution.